# Using Inbuilt Help in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to register a new source to get packages when running apt-get to finally install azure-iot-sdk-c-dev to use the code to communicate to IoT Hub.

When I run this command

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXX

I run into issues but this post is not about reviewing the issue I am facing, I want to understand first what my commands even mean. So I tried building my understanding using --help but I think I may not be connecting all the dots.

For example, to understand what sudo is; I typed sudo --help and I could built some understanding around it.

My question is why do I not see a mention of apt, when I type sudo --help or there is one and I am overlooking?

After typing sudo --help, I get the following but no mention of apt?
Note: Please move to superuser forum if that's where the question belongs.

> sudo - execute a command as another user
>
> usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h
>   host] [-p prompt] [-u user] usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h
>   host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command] usage: sudo
>   [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
>   prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [] usage: sudo -e
>   [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt]
>   [-u user] file ...
>
> Options:   -A, --askpass               use a helper program for
>   password prompting   -b, --background            run command in the
>   background   -C, --close-from=num        close all file descriptors >=
>   num   -E, --preserve-env          preserve user environment when
>   running command   -e, --edit                  edit files instead of
>   running a command   -g, --group=group           run command as the
>   specified group name or ID   -H, --set-home              set HOME
>   variable to target user's home dir   -h, --help
>   display help message and exit   -h, --host=host             run
>   command on host (if supported by plugin)   -i, --login
>   run login shell as the target user;   -K, --remove-timestamp
>   remove timestamp file completely   -k, --reset-timestamp
>   invalidate timestamp file   -l, --list                  list user's
>   privileges or ...   -n, --non-interactive       non-interactive mode,
>   no prompts are used   -P, --preserve-groups       preserve vector
>   instead of setting to target's   -p, --prompt=prompt         use the
>   specified password prompt   -r, --role=role             create
>   security context with specified role   -S, --stdin
>   read password from standard input   -s, --shell                 run
>   shell as the target user;   -t, --type=type             create
>   security context with specified type   -U, --other-user=user       in
>   list mode, display privileges for user   -u, --user=user
>   run command (or edit file)    -V, --version               display
>   version information and exit   -v, --validate              update
>   user's timestamp without running a command   --
>   stop processing command line arguments

Comment: `apt-key` is the command part in "*execute a command as another user*" and *`sudo ... [command]`*.

Comment: @melpomene So I shouldn't expect to see explicit entries, then how would I learn explore. :(

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `man`

Like `man sudo` or `man apt`

Ultimately, the reason you don't see any help for `apt` from `sudo`, is because they're *entirely different* executables. `apt` is the Debian package manager, `sudo` is the ***s***uper **u**ser **do** command.

`sudo` *calls* `apt` with `sudo apt` - in other words, if you ran `apt` *without* `sudo` you wouldn't execute it with super user permissions and it would likely fail if not otherwise run as root.

Comment: More like **s**ubstitute **u**ser **do**.

Comment: It originally stood for superuser do and still does. Learn your history.

Comment: Interesting. I've tried to learn my history, but I've run into difficulties. E.g. the [Wikipedia page on sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) cites a [blog post about su](https://pthree.org/2009/12/31/the-meaning-of-su/), but knowing what `su` originally stood for (back when it couldn't switch to other users than `root`) doesn't really help with `sudo`. What's your source?

Comment: `su` is not `sudo` and they don't do the same thing so saying the *su* part of `sudo` is the same as the *su* in `su` is not the same. https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html. "`sudo` allows a permitted user to execute a command as the ***superuser* or another user**" and that's straight from the sudo project site manpage.